# Changing a color of circle after mousePressed

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have to change a color of spot to 'red' when mousePressed, then it should be back to its original color when mouseRelease. This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class PanelTwo extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    public Spot spot = new Spot(100,100,20);
    //public Color f = new Color(250,0,0);
    public PanelTwo(){
        super();
        setLayout (new FlowLayout());
        //setOpaque(true);
        addMouseListener(this);

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        spot.draw(g);
    }
    @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
    @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            spot.x=e.getX();
            spot.y=e.getY();
            repaint();  
        }
    @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
    @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
}
```

And there is another code with information about my shape

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Spot {
    public int x,y,r;
    public Color c= new Color(100,150,200);
    public Color f = new Color(250,0,0);
    public Spot(int X, int Y, int R){
        x=X; y=Y; r=R;
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillOval(x-r, y-r, 2*r, 2*r);
    }
}
```

So, I want to change the color of this ball after I press my mouse, and after I release - it should come back to the original color.

Comment: Okay, what's wrong with using spot.c, seen as the color property is public. Also, you're going to have some interesting painting issues if y don't call super.paintComponent first before performing custom painting

Comment: You've told us what you want your code to do, but not what it actually does. What *specific* problems are you having with your program?

Comment: I don't have specific problem with a code, it's fine. It allows me relocate a ball all around a field by pressing my mouse.

Comment: After I press a mouse to another part of a field my shape relocates to it.

Answer (score 1):

- When `mousePressed` is called, record the original color of `spot` and change its color
- When `mouseReleased` is called, reset `spot` to its original color

Comment: How to record an original color of a spot and change a color? Thats a problem that I can't solve

Comment: Make a instance field, called something like "oldColor" in paenlTwo. Use something like "oldColor = spot.c;"

Comment: The problem is that my object doesn't hold an color information.

Comment: Spot does and you can make PanelTwo hold color information...just add a field to store the value...

Answer (score 0):

i assume that the two colors in your class is the color when it is clicked and released. you can't change the color because you are setting the `Graphics.setColor()` method to a specific color which is `c` . try to make it more flexible.

```
public class Spot {
    public int x,y,r;
    public Color c= new Color(100,150,200);
    public Color f = new Color(250,0,0);
    //make the default color to c
    public Color currentColor = c;
    public Spot(int X, int Y, int R){
        x=X; y=Y; r=R;
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(currentColor);
        g.fillOval(x-r, y-r, 2*r, 2*r);
    }
}
```

and in your `mousePressed` or `mouseReleased` just change the `currentColor`

```
@Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        spot.x=e.getX();
        spot.y=e.getY();
        spot.currentColor = spot.f;
        repaint();  
    }
@Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        spot.x=e.getX();
        spot.y=e.getY();
        spot.currentColor = spot.c;
        repaint();  
    }
```